# copy a text file using c

Tags: c, arrays, string, file

What I want to do for now is have an input text file, load its content into a 2d array, perform something on it and then put it out into another file. Essential problem for me is keeping the original files' structure. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
 {
  FILE *ifp, *ofp;
  char buffer[100];
  int i, c;

  ifp=fopen("test.in", "r");
  ofp=fopen("test.out", "w");

  while (!feof(ifp)){
  if(fscanf(ifp, "%s", buffer) != 1)
   break;
  fprintf(ofp, "%s", buffer); 
}  
return 0;
}
```

my input:

```
aaa bb bbb
bbbbb bbbb aa
```

and output:

```
aaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbaa
```

Everything I tried for EOL or EOF recognition caused infinite loops. Performing anything with     "%c" instead of     "%s" resulted in worse outputs. Thanks in advance.
edit: I'm aware I can get the output to be words with spaces between them or have every word in a new line but I don't know how to get from here to final result.

Comment: Why not use `fgets`? That takes whole lines. You are reading words and then printing them to the file, which gets rid of whitespace. (`scanf` reads until whitespace, so words)

Comment: `getline()` could be very useful here if you need to preserve the structure of the file.

Comment: OT: But still related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: [while feof is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Use `"%c"`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  FILE *ifp, *ofp;
  char buffer;

  ifp=fopen("test.in", "r");
  if(ifp==NULL)return 1;
  ofp=fopen("test.out", "w");
  if(ofp==NULL){
    fclose(ifp);
    return 1;
  }

  for(;;){
    if(fscanf(ifp, "%c", &buffer) != 1)
      break;
    fprintf(ofp, "%c", buffer); 
  }
  fclose(ifp);
  fclose(ofp);
  return 0;
}
```

or `getc()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  FILE *ifp, *ofp;
  int buffer;

  ifp=fopen("test.in", "r");
  if(ifp==NULL)return 1;
  ofp=fopen("test.out", "w");
  if(ofp==NULL){
    fclose(ifp);
    return 1;
  }

  for(;;){
    if((buffer = getc(ifp)) != EOF)
      break;
    putc(buffer, ofp); 
  }
  fclose(ifp);
  fclose(ofp);
  return 0;
}
```

You won't neeed `feof()` because the functions used to read will detect EOF.

Also, don't forget to check if the files are successfully opened and to close the files opened.

Comment: you won't close the first file when opening second one fails.

Comment: @zoska Thank you. Fixed.

Comment: Spaces, new-lines and braces are free ...! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use **getline** function instead **fscanf**. Because **fscanf** can't read the full string which contain the space character

```
 while ((read = getline(&line, &len, stream)) != -1) 
 {
     printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :\n", read);
     printf("%s", line);
 }
```

See full detail about **getline**:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html